# FC Layer followed by LSTM - Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to work with LSTMs. My input data is 224*1 and my labels are 70*1.

Before connecting my inputs to LSTMs I'm trying to match the Input data to label values.

So i'm trying to use FC layer in the beginning, leave it to FC layer to learn the non-linear scale of Input-Label and then connect back the output of FC layer to LSTM.

I have tried using tf.reshape by flattening and reshape, it does not work has the size is different.

Can anyone help me with this ? Is this possibe at all?
My output of FC layer I am getting now is:

```
fc_layer:tf.Tensor 'Reshape:0' shape=(224, 70, 1) dtype=float32


Code
fc_layer = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs =                     
                 batchX_placeholder, num_outputs = 70, activation_fn = 
                                                          tf.nn.relu)
fc_layer = tf.reshape(fc_layer,[-1, 70 , 1])



#######RNN Layer
init_state = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [num_layers, 2, 
batch_size, state_size],name = 'init_state')

state_per_layer_list = tf.unstack(init_state, axis=0)
rnn_tuple_state = tuple(
[tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(state_per_layer_list[idx][0], 
state_per_layer_list[idx][1])
    for idx in range(num_layers)]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this by creating 2 FC layer back-to-back.

Inputs are [1,224]

```
fc_layer1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs, num_outputs = 224, activation_fn = tf.nn.relu)



fc_layer2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs = fc_layer1, num_outputs = 70, activation_fn = tf.nn.relu)
```

So now I have fc_layer2 with shape (1,70). My LSTM labels are (70). I think I can now proceed for LSTM design